# Put gesture recognizers in view or controller class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I was looking for GestureRecognizer tutorials on the web and saw that most people used for example `UIPanGestureRecognizer` directly in the view. Is this common practice, if so, why not in the controller?

I generate my views in the controller and have methods that I would need to call, when the gesture is used. How should the delegation method look like, if my gesture recognizer is in the view class, and the method to be called in the controller class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `UIGestureRecognizer` implementation, and the most common one in my opinion is as follows:

```
//this is where you create the view that you want to add the gesture recognizer
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[tapRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewTapped:)];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

After creating the gesture recognizer and adding it to a `UIView` subclass you can get the taps with the function you pointed above:

```
- (void)imageViewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ( gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized )
    {
        NSLog(@"tap recognized!");
    }
}
```

So basically, you dont need to worry about the controller/view dilemma.
You always add the gesturerecognizer to a view. and when adding the gesture recognizer you add a target function, which you need to implement in the controller class.

P.S [This SO Question might clarify in detail of the dilemma you are facing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7925488/874886)

> In one sense, yes, this violate the MVC pattern. As you say, the view shouldn't have anything to do with how to control it, it's a better habit to group such code in another part of the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag an gesture into the storyboard(into the view controller),too.Then from the document outline you make an action(in the vc) for that gesture